# Create an app using iOS 10 (beta) API with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is there any possibility to start creating an app for iOS 10 (using iOS 10 API) using Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Xcode beta and ios 10 sdk beta. Then update Xamarin from either beta or alpha channels.

Comment: But will that work with Xamarin's alpha channel if it's currently at 9.9.0 and does not have iOS 10 support?  Or are you saying, that will work once Xamarin has iOS 10 support?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 support is now available via a preview version (Xamarin.iOS 9.99.0.326). see https://releases.xamarin.com/preview-ios-10-xcode-8-sierra-support/

> NOTE – These builds have been tested against Xcode beta 2. It has compatibility with Xcode beta 3, however we are still testing against beta 3 to find any issues that may exist.
>
> There is no target stable date final iOS 10 support at this time, as we have to wait until Apple finalizes and publishes their support before we can release ours. That being said, we will do additional preview releases between now and the final Apple release, so be sure to check back and see if newer versions become available in the coming months.

---

<strike>iOS 10 is currently not supported. Using the Alpha Version of Xamarin iOS 9.9.0, which at the time of writing is the latest.</strike>

You can write the code and even compile the binaries however when you try and run on device or in simulator you will be given the following error message.

> Xamarin.iOS 9.9.0 does not support a deployment target of 10.0 for iOS (the maximum is 9.3). Please select an older deployment target in your project's Info.plist or upgrade to a newer version of Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: From where we can get news about the supported versions ?

Comment: There is a blog style release log here: https://releases.xamarin.com/category/alpha/

Comment: or change logs are here, but not updated as frequently: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.9/